# Accessing a dictionary value by custom object value in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, object

So I have a square that's made up of a series of points. At every point there is a corresponding value.

What I want to do is build a dictionary like this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y


square = {}    
for x in range(0, 5):
        for y in range(0, 5):
            point = Point(x,y)
            square[point] = None
```

However, if I later create a new point object and try to access the value of the dictionary with the key of that point it doesn't work..

```
>> square[Point(2,2)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    square[Point(2,2)]
KeyError: <__main__.Point instance at 0x02E6C378>
```

I'm guessing that this is because python doesn't consider two objects with the same properties to be the same object? Is there any way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define [`Point.__hash__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`Point.__eq__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) so that they can be compared properly within dicts.

And while you're at it, consider defining [`Point.__repr__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) so that you get decent-looking representations of your `Point` objects.

Comment: Thanks! Good tip about __repr__ but I'm a little bit confused about the difference between it and __str__?

Comment: `__repr__()` is used whenever you need a representation of the object, without actually wanting the string value, e.g. within the REPL.

Comment: `__repr__` should also return valid python, that could be passed as an arg to `eval` to create an object identical to the one being repr'd.   It should return the following string: `'Point(%s, %s)' % (self._x, self._y)`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, define the `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods on your Point class.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._x == other._x and self._y == other._y

    def __hash__(self):
        #This one's up to you, but it should be unique. Something like x*1000000 + y.
```

Comment: Thanks for the code breakdown, really helped! Wish I could pick you as an answer as well.

Comment: The __hash__() method can just be implemented as "return (x,y).__hash__()".

Answer (score 2):

Any reason not to just use a tuple:

```
>>> s={}
>>> s[1,2]=5
>>> s
{(1, 2): 5}
>>> s[1,2]
5
```

Comment: In that example I guess I could, but in my code the Point class has a few more properties so a tuple wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: Check out the namedtuple function in the collections module. I find it very useful for implementing struct-like objects, and it creates classes you can inherit from if you want to add additional methods.

Answer (score 2):

Steps : Implement a custom key class and override hash and equality function.

e.g.

```
class CustomDictKey(object):

def __init__(self, 
             param1,
             param2):

            self._param1 = param1
            self._param2 = param2

 # overriding hash and equality function does the trick

def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self._param1,
             self._param2))

def __eq__(self, other):
    return ( ( self._param1,
             self._param2 ) == ( other._param1,
             other._param2) )

def __str__(self):
    return "param 1: {0} param 2: {1}  ".format(self._param1, self._param2)
```

## main method

```
if name == 'main':

    # create custom key
    k1  = CustomDictKey(10,5)

    k2  = CustomDictKey (2, 4)

    dictionary = {}

    #insert elements in dictionary with custom key
    dictionary[k1] = 10
    dictionary[k2] = 20

    # access dictionary values with custom keys and print values
    print "key: ", k1, "val :", dictionary[k1]
    print "key: ", k2, "val :", dictionary[k2]
```

Refer the article [Using custom class as key in python dictionary](http://assortedtechnotes.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-use-custom-type-as-dictionary.html)  for complete details.